# Setting div's height according to browser height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to create html code using Bootstrap. But i have a problem. I don't adjust div's height according to a browser height. I tried everything i know.

How can I adjust the div's height browser height?

Here is my code:

```css
body{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#leftMenu{
    height: 500px;
}

#viewport{
    height: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#informationMenu{
    height: 100px;
    overflow: scroll;
}

#rightMenu{
    height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2" id="leftMenu" style="background-color: #cc0052" >
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
                <div class="row" id="viewport" style="background-color: aquamarine">
                </div>
                <div class="row" id="informationMenu" style="background-color: cadetblue">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2" id="rightMenu" style="background-color: #bfff00">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Which div are we talking about?

Comment: Actually, I want to height of leftMenu and rightMenu is 100%, viewport height 80% and informationMenu height is 20%.

Comment: Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/smbtcfwf/   .... If yes, I'll post it as an answer as well

Comment: Yes it is working. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using `vh` for height. It also has responsive design. `1hv` = 1% of the viewport height (broswer), meaning that `100vh` will be the value you need ;)

Edit: If you're trying to do the same for width, you need to use `vw` instead of `vh` because `vh` refers to the height and `vw` refers to the width ;)

Comment: Yes it is working for height but now my width is not working:(

Comment: For  width you shoulde use `vw` instead of `vh` ;)

Comment: Glad it helped you and you also learned something you ;). Can you accept the answer to mark the question closed?